# Some kind of type map to determine one type from another?

Tags: typescript

The data I am working with has a list of possible keys, and when working with corresponding with that key, then I have a corresponding data type:

ie.

```
type PossibleKeys = "foo" | "bar" | "not-bar"; 

type FooData = {
    value: number; 
    name: string; 
}

type BarData = {
    address: string; 
    id: number; 
}

type NotBarData = {
    value: string; 
}
```

I'm looking for a way that I can conveniently map between the `PossibleKey` type to get the corresponding data type.

I have a currently solution that looks like this:

```
type PossibleKeys = "foo" | "bar" | "not-bar"; 

type FooData = {
    key: "foo"; 
    value: number; 
    name: string; 
}

type BarData = {
    key: "bar"; 
    address: string; 
    id: number; 
}

type NotBarData = {
    key: "not-bar"; 
    value: string; 
}

type AllPossibleTypes = FooData | BarData | NotBarData; 


type SpecialRecord = {
    [K in PossibleKeys ]: {
        key: K; 
        data: AllPossibleTypes & {key: K}; 
    }
}

const myRecord  : SpecialRecord= {
    foo: {
        key: "foo", 
        data: {
            key: "foo", 
            value: 9, 
            name: "foo string", 
        }, 
    }, 
    bar : {
        key: "bar", 
        data: {
            key: "bar", 
            address: "9999 hello", 
            id: 99123
        }
    }, 

    "not-bar" : {
        key: "not-bar", 
        data: {
            key: "not-bar", 
            value: "not bar string"
        }
    }
};
```

This relies using the `PossibleKey` type in the data type itself, and you can see it creates a lot of redundancy.

An alternative way to do this is to make use of conditional types, and create a chain of `K extends "foo" ?` checks, like so:

```
type SpecialRecord = {
    [K in PossibleKeys ]: {
        key: K; 
        data: K extends "foo" ? FooData : K extends "bar" ? BarData : K extends "not-bar" ? NotBarData : never; 
    }
}
```

I guess semantically this is the same as creating the kind of map in mind, but it looks pretty ugly. (In the use case I have in mind, I may have 20 or so of these types).

Is there a more elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a mapped object type and index it:

```
type TypeMap = {
    "foo": FooData; 
    "bar": BarData; 
    "not-bar": NotBarData
}

type DerivedType<T extends PossibleKeys> = TypeMap[T]; 

type PrintFoo = DerivedType<"foo">; 
//type PrintFoo = {
//    value: number;
//    name: string;
//}
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACg9gZwQSwEYBsIGkIgVAXigCIAzOOYqAHxNQEMAnK24gOzmAFoHmBuKAChBoSFABiFACL1g9QlADegqKqgA3eugCuEAFxQ22gLaoIjASrVt6x-VATBGyNgHNLAX2GjoAISYycgrKalD0ACbhjBBIBo7ObpahyOEGRqbmnt7g0ABynP6MgfJEIWqaOvbxLu5CXiI5UAAqOQCy9GDBVqpkFMQGknDFSWrEvP1QhcNCoeycPEwT+cBTsvSCXj5QUubI6hDhLZAAPE1QEAAewBBs4fjwSGiYOHgAfApHEO1gANpNALqWBpiGAJYCDBQ7Zz7Q45Y69SivIHA6AAZUgAGNkFoAEoQDFwRjhLqhH5YKAuWCIFAYbC4fD-AxlUKqADWuAMWBGLKg4TWBihewOn2OWCRMzUXg8QA)

Explanation:

Here I've declared type `TypeMap` but I don't use it directly.

In my type `DerivedType` I reference the TypeMap using an [index type.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types)

That is we are saying "For that mapped object type I just created - what are the values types I can access for these given key(s)".